# how to include graphs into html2pdf?

Tags: php, pdf, graph, charts

I am using maxChart.class.php to create Graphs and its working properly.

I am also using html2pdf.class.php to create Online pdf report. I tried to include chart in pdf file but its not working.

My code is

```
$rowval=$sqcat1->qcategory;
$data3["$rowval"]=$per;

$content = "
<page>


$content.=$mc3 = new maxChart($data3);    
  $mc3->displayChart('',1,450,400,true);
"    


</page>";

  require_once("/pdf1/html2pdf.class.php");
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output('demo.pdf');
```

How can i add graphs in file ?

Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used MPDF and SVGGraphs to do this

Code to add graphs value in php variable

```
$html.='<br>'.$graph->Fetch("CylinderGraph",true).'<br>';
```

Code for MPDF

```
include("/mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- make the chart an image and embed that image in the document, using `<img src=...`
- display the chart image using binary data `<img src="data:image/png;base64,binarycontentherebase64encoded...">`

Comment: Sir can you please describe that? How to make chart an images?

Comment: Your chart library (I assume it was written by a guy called Max) is using html/css to display the chart. I don't see in your code how you embeded this guy's Max css stylesheet (mandatory to display the chart). 2nd you should use something like Google Charts for your charts (get the image and embed that image in the pdf file).

Comment: Hi all i tried to include chart into mpdf but i can't able to success, i used google chart, maxChart, phpgraphlib to generate graphs and try to embed in pdf but nothing displayed. plese help me.